# Error trying to send message to serve Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: server, udp, client, ubuntu-18.04

When I try to send a quoted string from client to server, it works. However, when i try to send a variable storing the input of the user to the server, it does not. Anybody knows why?

**server_file**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

s.bind( ("0.0.0.0", 1234) )

buff, addr = s.recvfrom(100)

print buff, addr
```

**client_file**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

nume_user = input()
# s.sendto( nume_user, ("127.0.0.1", 1234) ) # this does not work

s.sendto("john", ("127.0.0.1", 1234) ) # this works

buff, addr = s.recvfrom(100)

print buff
```

This is the error that I am getting ( Ubuntu 18.04 LTS )

```
Traceback (most recent call last:
File "c4-1.py", line 5, in <module>                                                                
nume_user = input()                                                                            
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>                                                           
NameError: name 'ionut' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input):

> input([prompt])
> Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).

Thus it will read the string you enter (in this case `ionut`) and then eval it. Since `ionut` is not a declared variable or otherwise valid Python statement it will throw the error shown.

Also from the documentation:

> Consider using the raw_input() function for general input from users.

This is what you should use instead and then you don't get the error.

Apart from that consider using Python3 instead of Python2 which you currently use. Python2 is end of life and also the `input` function in Python3 is more what you seem to expect - see [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).